# How to show that the space $\mathcal{l}^1$ is connected

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

How can one show that the space $\mathcal{l}^1$ is connected?

$\mathcal{l}^1$ is the metric space of real sequences such that the sum of the absolute values of the entries converges. with metric $d_1(\{x_n\},\{y_n\}) = \Sigma_{n=1}^\infty |x_n-y_n|$.

Comment: The somewhat obvious first attempt to try would by to show *path* connectedness via convex combinations ...

Answer (score 2):

Every topological vector space is connected because it is path-connected.

To prove path-connectedness it is enough to construct a path between two arbitrary points $x,y\in X$. Clearly hte function
$$
\gamma:[0,1]\to X:t\mapsto ty+(1-t)x
$$
gives the desired path.

Comment: +1: And all that has to be shown is that $\gamma$ is continuous, and that $\gamma(t)\in\ell^1$ for each $t\in[0,1]$.